# WearOS Health Services Spot Measurements

Tags: wear-os, androidx, android-wear-2.0, healthconnect

Does WearOS Health Services allow taking spot measurements for anything other than `HEART_RATE_BPM`? I have tried [checking the list of capabilities](https://developer.android.com/health-and-fitness/guides/health-services/active-data/measure-client) on both a Google Pixel Watch 2 and the emulator, and the only item I get back is `DataType.HEART_RATE_BPM`:

```kotlin
val healthClient = HealthServices.getClient(this /*context*/)
val measureClient = healthClient.measureClient
lifecycleScope.launch {
    val capabilities = measureClient.getCapabilitiesAsync().await()
    // This is the only item in `capabilities.supportedDataTypesMeasure`
    supportsHeartRate = DataType.HEART_RATE_BPM in capabilities.supportedDataTypesMeasure
}
```

Comment: While developing for samsung devices I came up with the same problem... I didnt find a solution yet, but I found out that I can get other capabilities while "Samsung Health" app is running on foreground and a few minutes when it goes to background... Maybe the same goes for pixel watch...